# Can't get Datatables integrates with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatable

I'm trying to get TB3 integrated with DataTables as [this example](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap.html) show but I can't get it at all as you may see on the attached pic.

[image]

What's not working? The select element hasn't TB class applied, also the same with search box and finally the previous|next buttons. The only thing I do it here is add the [dataTableBootstrap.js](//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js) script and the [dataTableBootstrap.css](//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css) styles, the rest is a common TB3 table markup:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-condensed" id="dataTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Tipo de Trámite</th>
            <th>No. Solicitud</th>
            <th>Tipo de Solicitud</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        ... something goes here
    </tbody>
</table>
```

If I debug the page through Chrome I can see this errors in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageButton' of undefined dataTables.bootstrap.js:38

Is the [plugin/script](//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/725b2a2115b/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js) outdated or I'm missing something here? Any help or advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like this was an issue affecting the release from around the [9th July until patched on the 27th August 2014.](https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/issues/90)

The link you are using is a very specific version of the dataTables plugin, which was breaking the pagination.

You will want to use the links referenced on the Datatable CDN page - rather than ones you may have found on example code page:

http://cdn.datatables.net/

For reference the [latest version found](http://www.datatables.net/manual/styling/bootstrap) is:

**CSS:** http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.css

**JS:**  http://cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/a5734b29083/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js

Comment: It's not working I'm using the one you leave here and I got the same result

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue when trying to use the Bootstrap 3 integration with DataTables 1.9.4. The commit log inside the DataTables Plugins repository suggests that the plugins there were updated to DataTables 1.10 at some point.

I got it working by using the code from the repository at this commit:
https://github.com/DataTables/Plugins/tree/1f6bed3b750c258297ccef1b36e87ef9aed53660